# How to know if a certain file has been accessed/modified by some app?

Tags: android, file, android-file, android-log

My app should keep some files under watch. I want to detect any attempt to read/modify these files and which app did it so I can proceed accordingly.

Does Android log these types of actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are welcome to use `FileObserver` for this. However, please bear in mind that this requires a continuously-running process, and that's impractical on most versions of Android. Plus, it will require a `Notification` (particularly on Android O and above), which users may not appreciate, since it shows that your app is continuously running, and they may not want that.